# element in field, expressed as multiple of elements?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-fields

I'm new to the formal concept of a field, although I'm aware of the defining axioms. I've been struggling to think through the following idea:

Let F be a field. If I take an element a in F , is it always the case that I can find b and c in F such that  b•c = a?

Any thoughts would be helpful, thanks :)

Edit:
[Forgot to add this, but I mean b,c different from a]

Comment: Would $b=1$, $c=a$ fit the bill? But I have some lingering doubts about what kind of fields you have in mind. The question makes better sense if dealing with fields as concepts from abstract algebra. Then the real numbers would form one example of a field. Vector-fields OTOH are something else entirely. Even though they are formulated with tools from math only things like electro-magnetic fields and gravitational field from physics are possibly better known examples of vector fields.

Comment: I updated my answer to address your edit.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is "yes" but it isn't a particularly informative question.

Just think about the rational numbers for a moment. Suppose $a=2$. Then you have infinitely many solutions to your problem:
$$
2 =   1 \times 2  = 6 \times (1/3)  = (12/5) \times (5/6) = \cdots
$$

You should see how to generalize this for any $a$ in any field.